# How to say "Things could always be worse"

Tags: classical-latin, motto, contemporary-latin

For an ironic family crest, I would like to incorporate the motto "Things could always be worse" or a similar Latin saying.

Comment: Would you prefer an actual, attested motto or some new invention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from Terence's (Adelphoe III, 2, 46)

> Peiore res loco non potis est esse quam in quo nunc sitast
>
> Literally: *In a worse place the thing cannot be than it is now.*
> Not so literally: *Things cannot become any worse than they are now.*

⋯ we can construct:

> Peiore loco etiamnum res posset esse.

⋯ or, if you like it simpler:

> Peior etiamnum res posset esse.

Comment: Is "sitast" two words, "sit" and "ast", giving,, "...in quo nunc sit ast" = "...in which now at least it may be"? Why switch from present subjunctive, "sit" to imperfect subj., "posset" between the first & second/ third?

Comment: @tony sitast = sita est. Why the irrealis? Because I wanted to translate "**could** be worse". Admittedly, the indicative would have stayed closer to Terence's original.